# How to localize keyboard when InputScope is set to Number?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

I have an app written for Windows Phone 8 that I ported down-level to Windows Phone 7. The app deals with entering currency values so my TextBox has an InputScope of Number to make things easier to enter. I try to respect the locale setting so that in some countries the decimal in the currency value is represented by "." and in others it is represented by ",".

My issue is that it seems that the keyboard is not localized, so the user has to press and hold on the "." button to select the ",". I believe this may only be a WP7 issue. Unfortunately, some users don't know they can do this trick and thus think they are unable to enter currency values that have decimals in them. It also makes the app tedious to use for anyone that represents numbers this way.

Is there anything I am not setting properly or a workaround for this?

Thanks,

Miron

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it doesn't depend on culture, but you can set another `InputScope`, i.e. `CurrencyAmountAndSymbol` which contains both '.' and ','

Answer (score 0):

You may use `PostalCode` Input scope for your thing